# Checking Axiom for vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$$W =
\begin{cases}
x|  & \text{if xy >=0} \\[2ex]
y| & \text{}
\end{cases}
$$

With standard addition and scalar multiplication test the 10 axioms and see if they hold.

My trouble is how to test axioms such as the 4th axiom.

> 4. There is a zero vector 0 in V such that u + 0 = u

Would I plug in a value in for u to show that the identity holds? It seems that this identity will always hold true

Comment: What is $W$, too much context is missing to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero is not your problem.  $O$ = $(0,0)$ which is in $W$

You run into trouble with closure under addition.
$u = (-1,-2)$ is in $W$, and $v = (2,1)$ is in $W$, but $u+v$ is not.

(Assuming that addition is the standard vector addition.)